# Why use the <template> in WebComponent?

Tags: javascript, templates

I saw many examples of web components and everyone used template tags to draw screens. Is there a reason to use template tags instead of tags like <div> or <section>?

this is sample code

```
#render()
{
    if (!this.#template_node) this.#template_node = this.#get_default_template();

    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(this.#template_node.content.cloneNode(true));
}

#get_default_template()
{
    const template = document.createElement("template");
    template.innerHTML = `<p>Test Webcomponent</p>`

    return template;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, template elements aren't rendered with the rest of the page, but their contents is available for cloning and/or adding later with js. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template

Comment: I understand that. But even if a component uses a div tag instead of a template tag, isn't it the same that it doesn't draw on the screen until the component is connected to the DOM?

Comment: Yep. Thus making templates useful in that they can be attached without rendering. Using them also just increases the clarity of your code, as opposed to having a bunch of hidden divs serving a similar purpose.